# Apache 2 process stopped

Tags: django, apache, mod-fcgid

Today I made some changes, but only on fron-end side of my page and pushes those changes on the server. I checked if everything works under my domain and it was fine. But after about two hours I am getting only 500 Internal Server Error. I have such logs:

```
[Sun Jul 10 00:19:12 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 10 00:19:12 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Jul 10 00:19:12 2016] [info] mod_fcgid: Process manager 3584465 started
[Sun Jul 10 00:19:12 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 10 00:19:12 2016] [info] Server built: Mar 31 2015 17:28:57
[Sun Jul 10 00:19:12 2016] [info] mod_fcgid: server myuser:/home/.../django.fcgi(3584772) started
[Sun Jul 10 00:24:20 2016] [info] removed PID file /home/xxx/admin/apache/run/apache.pid (pid=3584452)
[Sun Jul 10 00:24:20 2016] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jul 10 00:24:21 2016] [info] mod_fcgid: process /home/.../django.fcgi(3584772) exit(shutting down), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0
[Sun Jul 10 00:24:21 2016] [info] mod_fcgid: Process manager 3584465 stopped
```

Can anyone provide a solution or some suggestions of how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're getting `SIGWINCH` which means window size has changed. Doesn't make much sense for a server though.

Okay, just found out `SIGWINCH` is misused by Apache to perform a graceful shutdown. Your question is a dup of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780853/what-is-in-apache-2-a-caught-sigwinch-error)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: It is somehow maitained throught server provider. I just configured .fcgi and .httaccess files and everything just started work. I didn't do anything by myselfe in case of running server.

Comment: Well, I have some good news and some bad news for ya. `SIGWINCH` is used to gracefully shut down Apache - that means there is something like a cron job, daemon or another entity shutting down Apache. I'll have to dup your question with another one that has as much a solution as I gave. There is no telling without accessing the server

Comment: Always this is a step toward. Thank you for explenation.