# Can not access to /admin django API rest with wsgi and Apache

Tags: python, django, admin, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am using django version 1.11 on a centos 7 OS. I deployed my rest api with apache and wsgi. Most of my non-auth apis run well in deployment phase, but when i tried to access to my admin page with the superuser, but i have an error 500 with apache and wsgi but not with the local runserver. Could someone help me with this ? Thanks

I have printed my error code below

```
[Wed Jul 12 11:12:33.433901 2017] [:error] [pid 427699] <QuerySet [<User: grf_star>]>
[Wed Jul 12 13:27:13.714040 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 427698] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jul 12 13:27:14.970278 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 431116] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jul 12 13:27:14.993828 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 431116] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 12 13:27:14.994874 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 431116] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jul 12 13:27:14.999724 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 431116] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 12 13:27:14.999782 2017] [core:notice] [pid 431116] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: Try to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780853/what-is-in-apache-2-a-caught-sigwinch-error

Comment: The SIGWINCH issue would be unrelated to a 500 error from Django. You should setup Django to log errors to stdout stream so capture in Apache error log. That or try setting DEBUG=True temporarily so error appears in browser. Right now Django is generating a 500 response but not logging why.

Comment: thanks, but i found the error, this was just a problem of apache's permissions. I resolved this problem by granting all permissions to the Apache user for my sqlite database. Thanks all