# Apache2 server is down - AH00170

Tags: ubuntu, crash-reports, apache2.4, php-7.4

I have been having problems for several weeks on my Apache2 server with Ubuntu 22.04.1 + PHP 7.4

For no apparent reason, the server goes down on its own and the web is still under construction so it does not receive traffic.

The last log I got before the server crashed contains these lines:

```
[Fri Mar 03 10:42:44.687695 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 756] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 10:42:44.687775 2023] [core:notice] [pid 756] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 03 11:12:28.440866 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 2882] [client 51.254.101.76:42478] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/code-execution.php, referer: https://purodeseo.es/wp-content/uploads/code-execution.php
Fri Mar  3 11:25:56 2023 (2778): Error Cannot kill process 778: Success!
[Fri Mar 03 21:08:02.583634 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 756] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me please,

Regards.

-I have tried to restart the server several times, it works again but when the server considers it appropriate, it crashes again.
-I have tried to look for my problem in stackoverflow but what I find that is related does not work for me.

Comment: This sounds like a problem that is more on-topic on serverfault.com than on StackOverflow

Comment: I think this question and its answers explain your log quite well - https://stackoverflow.com/q/780853/2846138. Your server gets a signal to gracefully shutdown, so it does. How exactly do you start your server? Is it a systemd service, or something else?

Comment: Hello @cyberbrain, I already read that post and understood the reason, but I can't solve the problem. There is only one CRON task that updates my vendor's products every 10 minutes.
I have the VPS server hosted at OVH and I access it through SSH, when the server crashes I restart it using the "reboot" command or through the OVH interface.

Comment: So if your vendors products are update every 10 minutes, don't you think this could be the reason for the stopping apache? Did you check if the times of update and server stop correlate?

Comment: I thought it might be, but actually the task runs every 10 minutes and succeeds several times before the server crashes. I even thought of increasing the "max_execution_time" value but it actually detects that a task is already running and doesn't launch it again until the current one is finished.