# Apache times out when starting and I cannot find any help from error logs

Tags: python, linux, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I am running (trying to) apache 2.4 on Rocky Linux 9.3. Here is my httpd.conf file.

```
LoadModule authz_core_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi_python3.so
LoadModule log_config_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule access_compat_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_core_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule filter_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule status_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule unixd_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule mpm_event_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so



WSGIPythonPath /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages

User apache
Group apache
LogLevel trace8
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
 

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /cert.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /keyfile.key


    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rack-search

    <Directory /var/www/html/rack-search>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess rack-search threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/rack-search/app.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/rack-search>
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

when I try to start it with

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

The service waits 90 seconds and then gives me the following rather dubious message.

httpd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
httpd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

The error log contains this

```
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.936394 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH01883: Init: Initialized OpenSSL library
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.936423 2023] [ssl:trace2] [pid 6512:tid 6512] ssl_engine_rand.c(125): Init: Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.937488 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.939522 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.53 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.53, Library: OpenSSL/3.0.7
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.942296 2023] [core:trace3] [pid 6512:tid 6512] core.c(3498): Setting LogLevel for all modules to trace8
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.952076 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH01883: Init: Initialized OpenSSL library
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.952086 2023] [ssl:trace2] [pid 6512:tid 6512] ssl_engine_rand.c(125): Init: Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.952092 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.952095 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.953497 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.53 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.53, Library: OpenSSL/3.0.7
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.953823 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(8488): mod_wsgi (pid=6512): Socket for 'rack-search' is '/etc/httpd/run/wsgi.6512.0.1.sock'.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.953858 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(8557): mod_wsgi (pid=6512): Listen backlog for socket '/etc/httpd/run/wsgi.6512.0.1.sock' is '100'.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954181 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6513:tid 6513] mod_wsgi (pid=6513): Starting process 'rack-search' with uid=48, gid=48 and threads=5.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954375 2023] [core:trace4] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mpm_common.c(538): mpm child 6514 (gen 0/slot 0) started
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954383 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] event.c(740): Child 0 started: pid 6514, gen 0, active 1/16, total 1/1/16
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954639 2023] [core:trace4] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mpm_common.c(538): mpm child 6515 (gen 0/slot 1) started
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954645 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] event.c(740): Child 1 started: pid 6515, gen 0, active 2/16, total 2/2/16
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954915 2023] [core:trace4] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mpm_common.c(538): mpm child 6516 (gen 0/slot 2) started
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954921 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] event.c(740): Child 2 started: pid 6516, gen 0, active 3/16, total 3/3/16
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954931 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH00489: Apache/2.4.53 (Rocky Linux) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9 OpenSSL/3.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954934 2023] [mpm_event:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH00490: Server built: Apr 28 2023 00:00:00
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954943 2023] [core:notice] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.954974 2023] [core:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] log.c(1574): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.955620 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6513:tid 6513] mod_wsgi (pid=6513): Initializing Python.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.956224 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Initializing Python.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.956265 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Initializing Python.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.956470 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Initializing Python.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.967403 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.967426 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.967795 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.969498 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Adding '/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages' to path.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.969499 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Adding '/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages' to path.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.969876 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Adding '/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages' to path.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.981298 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.981324 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.981435 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.982156 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6514:tid 6524] event.c(2401): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.982166 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6515:tid 6525] event.c(2401): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.982323 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6516:tid 6528] event.c(2401): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.985911 2023] [mpm_event:trace7] [pid 6514:tid 6602] event.c(1778): polling with timeout=-1 queues_timeout=-1689575176985910 timers_timeout=-1689575176985910
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.985946 2023] [mpm_event:trace7] [pid 6515:tid 6603] event.c(1778): polling with timeout=-1 queues_timeout=-1689575176985945 timers_timeout=-1689575176985945
[Mon Jul 17 09:26:16.986116 2023] [mpm_event:trace7] [pid 6516:tid 6604] event.c(1778): polling with timeout=-1 queues_timeout=-1689575176986116 timers_timeout=-1689575176986116
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045263 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6514:tid 6514] event.c(575): wake up listener
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045304 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6515:tid 6515] event.c(575): wake up listener
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045331 2023] [core:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH00096: removed PID file /etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid (pid=6512)
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045351 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6516:tid 6516] event.c(575): wake up listener
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045376 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6512:tid 6512] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045379 2023] [mpm_event:trace1] [pid 6514:tid 6514] event.c(2725): graceful termination received, joining workers
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045382 2023] [mpm_event:trace1] [pid 6515:tid 6515] event.c(2725): graceful termination received, joining workers
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045414 2023] [mpm_event:trace1] [pid 6516:tid 6516] event.c(2725): graceful termination received, joining workers
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045404 2023] [mpm_event:trace7] [pid 6515:tid 6603] event.c(1798): (4)Interrupted system call: polled with num=0 exit=1/0 conns=0 queues_timeout=-1689575267045403 timers_timeout=-1689575267045403
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045420 2023] [mpm_event:trace7] [pid 6514:tid 6602] event.c(1798): (4)Interrupted system call: polled with num=0 exit=1/0 conns=0 queues_timeout=-1689575267045419 timers_timeout=-1689575267045419
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045430 2023] [mpm_event:trace7] [pid 6516:tid 6604] event.c(1798): (4)Interrupted system call: polled with num=0 exit=1/0 conns=0 queues_timeout=-1689575267045429 timers_timeout=-1689575267045429
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045440 2023] [mpm_event:trace6] [pid 6515:tid 6603] event.c(1261): closing listeners (connection_count=0)
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045445 2023] [mpm_event:trace6] [pid 6514:tid 6602] event.c(1261): closing listeners (connection_count=0)
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.045599 2023] [mpm_event:trace6] [pid 6516:tid 6604] event.c(1261): closing listeners (connection_count=0)
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048094 2023] [mpm_event:trace1] [pid 6515:tid 6515] event.c(2729): graceful termination, workers joined, exiting
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048173 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Destroying interpreters.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048181 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048186 2023] [mpm_event:trace1] [pid 6514:tid 6514] event.c(2729): graceful termination, workers joined, exiting
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048390 2023] [mpm_event:trace1] [pid 6516:tid 6516] event.c(2729): graceful termination, workers joined, exiting
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048427 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Destroying interpreters.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048434 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048436 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Destroying interpreters.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.048442 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.049416 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Terminating Python.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.049428 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Terminating Python.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.049503 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Terminating Python.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.054849 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6516:tid 6516] mod_wsgi (pid=6516): Python has shutdown.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.055507 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6515:tid 6515] mod_wsgi (pid=6515): Python has shutdown.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:47.055596 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6514:tid 6514] mod_wsgi (pid=6514): Python has shutdown.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046487 2023] [core:trace4] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mpm_common.c(538): mpm child 6514 (gen 0/slot 0) exited
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046773 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] event.c(715): Child 0 stopped: pid 6514, gen 0, active 2/16, total 2/3/16, quiescing 1
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046795 2023] [core:trace4] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mpm_common.c(538): mpm child 6515 (gen 0/slot 1) exited
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046799 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] event.c(715): Child 1 stopped: pid 6515, gen 0, active 1/16, total 1/3/16, quiescing 1
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046814 2023] [core:trace4] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mpm_common.c(538): mpm child 6516 (gen 0/slot 2) exited
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046817 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 6512:tid 6512] event.c(715): Child 2 stopped: pid 6516, gen 0, active 0/16, total 0/3/16, quiescing 1
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046837 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mod_wsgi (pid=6513): Process 'rack-search' to be deregistered, as server is restarting or being shutdown.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.046846 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mod_wsgi (pid=6513): Process 'rack-search' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Mon Jul 17 09:27:48.057240 2023] [core:trace4] [pid 6512:tid 6512] mpm_common.c(434): end of generation 0
```

I have tried reinstalling apache, disabling SELinux and changing the configurations, but everything results in the same problem of apache timing out when starting.

Any hints/help would be useful. Thank you.

Edit:

/var/log/error.log has this in it

```
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.115990 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 3981:tid 3981] AH01914: Configuring server :443 for SSL protocol
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.116008 2023] [ssl:trace3] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(649): Using OpenSSL/system default SSL/TLS protocols
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.116013 2023] [ssl:trace3] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(670): Creating new SSL context (protocols: default)
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.116705 2023] [ssl:trace1] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(1057): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP]
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.116752 2023] [ssl:debug] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(528): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.117875 2023] [ssl:trace3] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_util_ssl.c(436): [:443] modssl_X509_match_name: expecting name 
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.117924 2023] [ssl:debug] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_util_ssl.c(451): AH02412: [:443] Cert matches for name 
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.117941 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 3981:tid 3981] AH02568: Certificate and private key :443:0 configured from 
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.131177 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 3981:tid 3981] AH01914: Configuring server :443 for SSL protocol
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.131185 2023] [ssl:trace3] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(649): Using OpenSSL/system default SSL/TLS protocols
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.131188 2023] [ssl:trace3] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(670): Creating new SSL context (protocols: default)
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.131497 2023] [ssl:trace1] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(1057): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP]
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.131538 2023] [ssl:debug] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_engine_init.c(528): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.132419 2023] [ssl:trace3] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_util_ssl.c(436): [:443] modssl_X509_match_name: expecting name 
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.132452 2023] [ssl:debug] [pid 3981:tid 3981] ssl_util_ssl.c(451): AH02412: [:443] Cert matches for name 
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.132458 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 3981:tid 3981] AH02568: Certificate and private key :443:0 configured 
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.146650 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.160590 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.161383 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3988] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9115): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Started thread 0 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.161400 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3989] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9115): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Started thread 1 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.161475 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3990] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9115): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Started thread 2 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.162139 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3994] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9115): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Started thread 3 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.162171 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3995] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9115): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Started thread 4 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.272855 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Shutdown requested 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.273045 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Stopping process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.273056 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3995] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9096): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Exiting thread 4 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.273053 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3990] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9096): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Exiting thread 2 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.273092 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Destroying interpreters.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.273096 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3994] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9096): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Exiting thread 3 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.273117 2023] [wsgi:debug] [pid 3982:tid 3989] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9096): mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Exiting thread 1 in daemon process 'rack-search'.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.273129 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.274258 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Terminating Python.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.280224 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Python has shutdown.
[Mon Jul 17 12:28:50.280243 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3982:tid 3982] mod_wsgi (pid=3982): Exiting process 'rack-search'.
```

and journalctl -ex prints this

```
Jul 17 12:27:19 user systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit httpd.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit httpd.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3168.
Jul 17 12:27:19 user httpd[3981]: [Mon Jul 17 12:27:19.102924 2023] [core:trace3] [pid 3981:tid 3981] core.c(3498): Setting LogLevel for all modules to trace8
Jul 17 12:27:21 user sudo[4074]:    admin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano error.log
Jul 17 12:27:21 user sudo[4074]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by admin(uid=1000)
Jul 17 12:27:27 user sudo[4074]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 17 12:27:29 user sudo[4076]:    admin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano error.log
Jul 17 12:27:29 user sudo[4076]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by admin(uid=1000)
Jul 17 12:27:42 user sudo[4076]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 17 12:27:43 user systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3284.
Jul 17 12:27:43 user systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jul 17 12:27:43 user systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished successfully.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3284.
Jul 17 12:27:43 user systemd[1]: run-credentials-systemd\x2dtmpfiles\x2dclean.service.mount: Deactivated successfully.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit run-credentials-systemd\x2dtmpfiles\x2dclean.service.mount has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jul 17 12:28:49 user systemd[1]: httpd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 17 12:28:50 user systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit httpd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'timeout'.
Jul 17 12:28:50 user systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit httpd.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit httpd.service has finished with a failure.
```

Edit

sudo httpd -S prints this

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443           mydns.dns (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:30)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/etc/httpd/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/etc/httpd/run/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

Comment: check if you are able to capture pstack during the Apache httpd startup. It will show what exactly thread taking time to start httpd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: I do not know.

Main points of attempted solutions: Disabled/enabled firewall, restarted server and services, reinstalled dnf and the its db, reinstalled all services, tried with different configurations and applications locally and remotely.

Solution: reinstall Linux

Answer (score 0):

I can see the following two lines:

```
 AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
 AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

Due to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780853/what-is-in-apache-2-a-caught-sigwinch-error) it maybe means:

> do you run apache2 in foreground in an open tty ? If yes, this is not
> recommended (alas), and you'll probably easily hit this SIGWINCH
> gracefull shutdown quite easily when resizing your controlling
> terminal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using PuTTY to SSH to the server, but I am not doing any terminal resizing as far as I recall. However I will go attempt to start apache without an SSH client by walking to the server.

Comment: I tried running sudo systemctl start httpd but the problem still persists and the error log prints the same bunch of messages as before. Thank you for the hint regardless!

Comment: Have you also checked error log /var/log/error.log? Maybe there is a subfolder apache2/ or httpd/ to also check for error logs. Also journalctl -ex?

Comment: Yeah, I checked them but nothing that caught my (quite junior and untrained) eye, so I did not post them originally, but I added them to the post now. I had to censor all of the DNS names, IPs and CSR info for security and privacy reasons, hope it does not obfuscate the logs too much. Thanks, again!

Comment: And  sudo httpd -S  does not show any errors in configuration? Is DNS blocked for httpd?

Comment: I get the correct result with nslookup mydns.dns, so it should be fine, however sudo httpd -S raises some peculiarities. The Main DocumentRoot: points to a file called /etc/httpd/htdocs and as for the VirtualHost Configuration: it says *:443 mydns.dns (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:30) which I am not sure how to interpret and lastly the server root is set to /etc/httpd.

I added the output to the main post. There are no error flags, but some things that raised my eyebrow.

Comment: You should try to add some ServerName value in your httpd.conf.

Comment: Added ServerName and ServerAdmin but the issue remains. I am starting to believe that the issue is not with the httpd configuration but rather with the actual OS, since dnf/yum install does not install all of the files for a package that it is supposed to and running "rpm -Va | grep missing" shows a lot of missing files for the httpd, but yum reinstall httpd does not fix the missing files.